# Autonomous behaviour via Orbbasic or streaming?

Tags: sphero-api

The Orbbasic language is suggested as a good way for kids to have hands on controlling the sphero in this [interview](http://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/1alx8f/i_am_the_founder_of_the_sphero_the_worlds_first/).

What are the limitations of orbbasic? Does it achieves the same 1ms granularity as macros ?
In which range of time granularity would it be equally acceptable to stream the data and excecute orbbasic?
Can the stabilization of sphero motion be programmed with orbbasic? with data streaming?

Answer (score 6):

You can read all about the abilities of orbBasic in our online document here:

https://github.com/orbotix/DeveloperResources/tree/master/docs

But in short, you can run about 9,000 lines of code/sec so it's 9x the density of macros but with more power. You can use print statements to send data back to the Bluetooth client but you have to make sure you don't exceed some rational limits; orbBasic can generate data faster than Bluetooth can transmit it to some devices.

Stabilization can be turned on and off in orbBasic, and when on you can generate your own roll commands that are processed exactly as if they came from a smartphone.

Just to be clear, data streaming is just an automated way of retrieving sensor data from Sphero without having to continually ask for it. You can use it to examine the motion of Sphero but you cannot "control" Sphero with it (since that implies sending commands to the robot; data streaming is just reading).

Dan Danknick

FW Engineer, Orbotix